# PHP: How do you get the book weight and category/genre using the Amazon API?

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-web-services

I have the following:

```
$amazon = new Zend_Service_Amazon($this->AMAZON_API_KEY, 'US', $this->AMAZON_API_SECRET);
$book   = $amazon->itemLookup($isbn,
  array(
    'SearchIndex'   => 'Books',
    'AssociateTag'  => 'NON ASSOCIATE',
    'IdType'        => 'ISBN',
    'ResponseGroup' => 'Large,ItemAttributes,Images,EditorialReview',
  )
);
```

It returns quite a bit of info, but not the weight or category/genre. How can I get the weight and category?

Answer (score 0):

The information returned by Amazon is determined by the specified ResponseGroup.  Details of what each response group contains is best obtained from the Amazon documentation.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_ResponseGroupsList.html

Points to note here are:

- As you have noted, you can specify multiple response groups by separating them with a comma.
- The small, large and medium responses are actually groups of several of the smaller responses.  Sometimes it is easier to specify one of these if it contains all the info you are after.
- Weight is a child of ItemAttributes/ItemDimensions (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_response_elements.html#Weight)
- Category, try Genre.